# Race Condition When Clicking Links on Page

Tags: gwt, web-applications

In my web app, the left-hand side has buttons.

The right-hand side shows a display based on which left-hand button was pressed.

Sometimes, a user will do the following:

```
 1. Press button 1
 2. wait 1-3 seconds
 3. Get reasonably frustrated and click button 2
 4. button 1's display shows up instead
```

If I understand correctly, then the server-to-client request for button 1 gets served up before button 2.

I'm thinking other web developers have run into this issue. How should it be approached?

Thanks,
Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

Are the button clicks resulting in AJAX requests? If so, either disable the buttons while the resource is being fetch and show a loading image or cancel any existing AJAX request when the button is clicked before making another request. For example:

```
  var request;
  $('#button1').click(function(event) {
    if (request && typeof request.abort == 'function') request.abort()
    request = $.post(...)
  });
```

The request is almost certainly going to continue server side depending on a lot of factors however client side the function that would be executed to show the result of the request no longer will be run.

Comment: Hi Cymen. You say, "cancel any existing AJAX request when the button is clicked before making another request." If the user completes step 3, then the user already made 2 AJAX requests: button 1 and 2. What does 'cancel the request' mean?